# Why is rand() giving me numbers outside of my defined interval? (It worked fine yesterday)

Tags: c++, random, ctime

I am generating random integers between 1000, and 11000. However they must have a mean of 6000. I used this snip of code in my program yesterday and it worked just fine, but now it gives me huge numbers as if my interval doesn't matter.

Edit: Stripped the code down a bit for easier reading.

```
srand(time(NULL));
int k = 5;
int cTotal = 0;
int cAverage = 0;

  struct process {
    int pid; // process id
    int cycles; // number of cycles required to complete the process
    int mSize; // size of the memory footprint
};

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {

        processes[i].pid = i; // set the unique identifier of the process.

        // If statements for determining the number cycles in each process
        if (k == 0) {
            processes[i].cycles = 6000; // if the user decides to try only one process, the average must be 6000, so assign 6000 as its value.
            cTotal += processes[i].cycles; //update the total number of cycles, and the average.
            cAverage = cTotal / (i + 1);

        } else if (cAverage == 0) { // if we have more than 1 process and  it happens to be the first one, go ahead and randomize it since we can adjust the average after the first iteration.
            processes[i].cycles = rand() % 11000 + 1000; //update the total number of cycles, and the average.
            cTotal += processes[i].cycles;
            cAverage = cTotal / (i + 1);

        } else if (cAverage == 6000 && i != k - 1) { // if the average is already at 6000, it's safe to choose any random number so do that unless this is the last iteration of the loop.
            processes[i].cycles = rand() % 11000 + 1000; //update the total number of cycles, and the average.
            cTotal += processes[i].cycles;
            cAverage = cTotal / (i + 1);

        } else {
            processes[i].cycles = (6000 * (i + 1)) - cTotal; // set the number of cycles such that the average will be 6000
            cTotal = cTotal + processes[i].cycles; //update the total number of cycles, and the average.
            cAverage = cTotal / (i + 1);
        }
    } //for
```

Edit2: Here is some of the output from my program (includes this plus another identical if statement for memory size)

```
    How many processes would you like to simulate? - >5
  5
Simulating 5 Processes...
***********************
PID: 0
Cycles: 63
Mem Size: 1877994624
***********************
PID: 1
Cycles: -23
Mem Size: 1877936645
***********************
PID: 2
Cycles: -1877936648
Mem Size: 13
***********************
PID: 3
Cycles: -1877936641
Mem Size: 64
***********************
PID: 4
Cycles: -1877936685
Mem Size: 4201340
***********************
Total Cycles: 30000
Average Cycles: 6000
Average Memory: 376427625 KB
```

Comment: This is a lot of code.  Can you narrow down the problem to a few lines of code?

Comment: Sure, I've just gotten flagged before for not having fully compilable code so I was being safe.

Comment: It is a delicate balance.  You want to give us compile-able code, but not so much that we have to hunt for the problem.

Comment: Indeed. Although it stuck out like a sore thumb to an old cat who's spent too long using random numbers.

Comment: I've edited the question to be stripped down, however I think my output makes less sense now, so if there is any confusion let me know.

Answer (score 7):

You need rand() % 10000 + 1000 for your range.

Put yesterday down to a statistical anomaly.

There are better ways (this approach has statistical bias towards lower numbers). Look at std::uniform_int_distribution, and consider using Mersenne Twister as the actual generator.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I think you identified a smaller problem I would have had after more testing which is slightly larger numbers than expected. I'll edit my question to include some outputs that I received to better clarify the question.

Comment: I've managed to fix my error, but I don't want to take away from your answer here. I found a variable mistake that was messing with the cycle numbers in the code that I deleted from the question.